# Azure setup question about multiple sites built from the same codebase

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

My website is running on Azure and I deploy via the Deployment slots feature. When code gets pushed to my production branch, my "staging" site gets the code, I check to make sure it's ok, then I do the "swap" with production site. All is well.

Now, I need to create a 2nd production website, where the only difference is a couple settings in my appsettings.json file.

So, my question is, how do I setup my 2nd production site with the deployment slots? Since there would be 2 production sites, and 1 staging site.

Or, should I make a completely new instance of the website in Azure, then setup that one with it's own deployment slot so I can have a staging for that one also?

Like this:

code => staging.site.com => site.com

code => staging.second.site.com => second.site.com

or

code => staging.site.com => site.com & second.site.com

Would it cause a problem having 2 sites referencing the same BitBucket repo, as well as the same branch?